Tag descriptions
I just approved a bunch of tag descriptions I'm not exactly heppy with, as they all begin with "Questions about...".
I'm slightly too lazy to rephrase them myself, but I thought it's better to get the momentum going by starting with something rather than nothing.
And anyway, I think we should make sure we have a consistent format on tag wikis and descriptions. i'm not familiar enough with SE to know the best way to deal with it, so can veterans please chime in and say what's best?
I suggest we take one or two tags as examples and discuss here the best formulations. Maybe one respone per formulation, upvote= agree, downvote= disagree, as is the custom?
Let's take customization. don't forget to state wiki and excerpt.
It would be nice it this can be settled before end of private beta, but that may be too optimistic.

Well I didn't want to change them myself not only out of laziness, but because I think there's no reason to try to impose my style. As for yours, I wouldn't say they are bad, in the contrary I think they're a good starting point and way better than nothing, which is why I approved them. (Plus, you have no idea how much I love the sensation of being able to approve things)


Excerpt 

Custom-made modifications done to original LEGO elements.

Full wiki 

Customizations of LEGO elements are a way to obtain new elements better suited for one's need.
These may include: custom stickers, brick painting or printing, cutting of rope or hose to desired length, cutting of a baseplate to desired size, brick engraving, brick melting, trimming, merging, or even custom molding.
Customization can also cover inclusion of non-LEGO elements in LEGO creations.

I like this format and it's good for many; But I'm having great difficulty coming up with one for Buying - a general excerpt would leave it too open, so being more specific and starting with "Questions about..." or "For questions around..." seems to fit there.

Yeah, the same goes for [tag:identification], I don't really see how to get rid of the "questions about..." at least in the excerpt. Frankly, I'm a completely useless at tagging :-)
